# Difference between Base address and actual address in debugger

Tags: reverse-engineering, assembly, debugging

I was looking was different functions in immlib library of Immunity debugger. 
I launched the python shell in the debugger and ran following commands:

```
>>>imm.assemble("jmp esp")
'\xff\xe4'

>>>imm.search("\xff\xe4")
[2090082029, 4411432, 2011716026, 2011814593, 2011483641, 2011550166, 2012419704, 1714392763, 1714402743, 2011113280, 2011241515, 2011395627, 2011399149, 2010689290, 2010819775, 2010819791, 2010819803, 2010845836, 2010849532, 2010849836, 2010851408, 2010855771, 2010855971, 2010856648, 2010856656, 2010856660, 2010857271, 2010857704, 2010857708, 2010857712, 2010857855, 2010857908, 2010857916, 2010858051, 2010859271, 2010860975, 2010863952, 2010864044, 2010864056, 2010864200, 2010864484, 2010864488, 2010864492, 2010866771, 2010866843, 2010867036, 2010882823, 2010883011, 2010890923, 2010893560, 2010897288, 2010897596, 2010903483, 2010903683, 2010904360, 2010904368, 2010904372, 2010905416, 2010905420, 2010905424, 2010905620, 2010905628, 2010906983, 2010908687, 2010911155, 2010911372, 2010911496, 2010911624, 2010911628, 2010911632, 2010911668, 2010911760, 2010911948, 2010912060, 2010912064, 2010912192, 2010912343, 2010912471, 2010914759, 2010938463, 2010938479, 2010938491]

>>>imm.findModule(2090082029)

('ntdll.dll', 2089811968)
```

So the first command assembles the "jmp esp" instruction.
The next command searches for the assembled instruction in the memory space.
Then the last command(imm.findModule) locates all the modules that contain the assembled instruction.

My query is with the addresses returned in the second and third command.

Does the addresses returned in the second command belong only to the memory space of the debugged process or the debugger searches for the entire available memory space to search for the assembled instruction ?

If I am not wrong, the address returned for the third command `('ntdll.dll', 2089811968)` is the base address of the module itself?

My next query is how do I identify if a module is in current program's memory space?

My last query sums up these, What would be the difference between Base address and actual address ?

Comment: GetModuleHandle is the API to see if a module is loaded into memory. I don't use Python nor immunity debugger but you should able to invoke that API to check. There is no such thing in terms of debugging as actual address (Unless you're talking about physical address?). The base address is the EP of the module, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the addresses returned in the second command belong only to the memory space of the debugged process or the debugger searches for the entire available memory space to search for the assembled instruction ?

The former. Code running in one specific process can only directly "see" memory in that same process.

> If I am not wrong, the address returned for the third command ('ntdll.dll', 2089811968) is the base address of the module itself?

You are not wrong :)

> My next query is how do I identify if a module is in current program's memory space?

As just discussed this will always be the default. To really access memory in another process' memory space you must use ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory.

> My last query sums up these, What would be the difference between Base address and actual address ?

Base address usually refers to the loading address of a module - that is, where the PE header for the module sits in memory. The rest of the module's headers, code, and data (the parts of it that are mapped to memory) then follow, subject to the module's specified page alignment.

It's a bit unclear what you mean by 'actual address' here - the actual address of ntdll.dll's header in memory is the same as the base address. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This indeed solves my problems. By actual address I was referring to the physical address.